# how do I change link properties in only a certain class?

Tags: html, css

I have this class called citation, that I am applying to some things ..

```
.Citation
{ 
    font-size:16px; 
    color:green; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight:600; 
    font-family:georgia, times new roman; 


}
```

mainly what I want to do though is change hyperlink styling with this class, because that's what it's to be applied to. I want to be able to apply the class so to certain hyperlinks, for example:

```
<span class="Citation"> <a href="www.google.com">yatayatayata</a></span></span>
```

I tried it this way

```
.Citation
{ 


    a {textd-ecoration:none }


}
```

and this way

```
a.Citation 
{ 

    font-size:16px; 
    color:green; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight:600; 
    font-family:georgia, times new roman;


}
```

And neither of them works so help me please?

Comment: post your html structure or setup a  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are none of the below answers satisfactory, @SebSilver?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the class  `Citation` on the links that you want to apply:

```
<a class="Citation" href='http:www.google.com'>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct css selector for your attempt is:

```css
.Citation a {
    /* stuff here */
}
```

This will select all anchor tags with the in a tag with class `.Citation`.

You can also use the direct-descendant selector:

```css
.Citation > a {
    /* stuff here */
}
```

Of course @William Seiti Mizuta's answer is another way to do it, a bit simpler in terms of the markup you have to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.Citation{
    font-size:16px; 
    color:green; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight:600; 
    font-family:georgia, times new roman; 
}

<a href="google.com" class="Citation">Style Applied</a>

<a href="yahoo.com">Style not applied</a>
```